# Netsuite cannot sent Email using suitelet

Tags: email, netsuite, suitescript

```
    /**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/email'],
/**
 * @param {email} email
 */
function(email) {

    /**
     * Definition of the Suitelet script trigger point.
     *
     * @param {Object} context
     * @param {ServerRequest} context.request - Encapsulation of the incoming request
     * @param {ServerResponse} context.response - Encapsulation of the Suitelet response
     * @Since 2015.2
     */
    function onRequest(context) {


            var senderId = 1601;
            var recipientEmail = '**@**.com';

            email.send({
                author: senderId,
                recipients: recipientEmail,
                subject: 'Test Sample Email Module',
                body: 'email body'
            });
    }
    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };

});
```

I tested this code in debugger and the mail was getting delivered,but when i deploy it in my test account the mail is not delivered .But i can see the log that the mail has been sent. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by test account you mean a NetSuite sandbox account.  This being the case, check settings at Setup > Company > Email Preferences under '   Sandbox and Release Preview'.  All sandbox emails except security sensitive messages - like password resets - get routed according to the rules there.  If "SEND EMAIL TO LOGGED IN USER" is selected it may fail due to the Suitelet not having a logged in user in its context.  NetSuite recommends using the "SEND EMAIL TO" option and specifying addresses there.

Comment: You mean we need to add all the email address there?
I think its practically difficult In case of bulk emails

Comment: @EdwinThomas, are you planning to send bulk emails from the sandbox account? This behaviour is specific to the sandbox and meant to avoid unwanted delivery of emails. In a production account the emails would be delivered without the need for additional settings.